# Does diff list all different lines after comparing two files?

Tags: bash, diff

```
diff file1 file2
```

Does `diff file1 file2` list all different lines between `file1` and `file2` ,including all unprintable chracters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will print all different lines between the two files, **unless** any of the file contains binary characters.

Examples:
With **whitespace**:

```
echo 'difftest ' > diff1
echo 'difftest' > diff2
diff diff1 diff2
```

Output:

```
1c1
< difftest 
---
> difftest
```

With **newline**:

```
echo 'difftest ' > diff1
echo 'difftest\n' > diff2
diff diff1 diff2
```

Output:

```
1c1,2
< difftest 
---
> difftest
>
```

With **binary character** (NULL):

```
echo 'difftest\0' > diff1
echo 'difftest' > diff2
diff diff1 diff2
```

Output:

```
Binary files diff1 and diff2 differ
```